# Create TabularInline for model that has FK relationship to parent of the registered model

Tags: django, django-admin

**Disclaimer**: I'm new to Django, so I'm still learning the Django way of doing things.

The project I'm working on has a u`User` model and a `Student` model. Previously, the `UserAdmin` was doing double duty for both models, but now the time has come to create an independent `StudentAdmin` that allows admins to easily edit/create/etc students.

`User` contains base info for `Student` (i.e. first and last name, email, phone, etc.) and `Student` contains more info (i.e. parent phone, class, todos, etc.). Related models like 'Class', 'Grade', etc. have FK relationships to `User`, which at first didn't strike me as an issue.

But when I went to reuse the inline classes created for `UserAdmin` in the new `StudentAdmin`, I've run into this error: `<class 'my_project.admin.TodoInline'>: (admin.E202) 'my_project.Todo' has no ForeignKey to 'my_project.Student`. This isn't surprising, so I thought I could merely override the `_init_` method on TodoInline to use `parent_model.user`, but then I ran into errors relating to `ForwardOneToOneDescriptor` and missing `_meta` fields. Given this use case, I believe there has to be a solution to this, but I'm currently at a loss for Django-related vocabulary for researching this issue further.

```
class TodoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Todo
    fields = ['content', 'completed', 'category', 'due_date']
    verbose_name_plural = "To-do's"
    extra = 0

    # This doesn't work:
    def __int__(self, parent_model, admin_site):
        super(TodoInline, self).__init__(parent_model.user, admin_site)
```

If the answer to this issue is to redefine the FK relationships between models, that's something I can't do at the moment. I need a solution that will allow me to reorient the inline classes (`TodoInline` is just one of many that I need for `StudentAdmin`) to use the related `User` model on the `Student` model. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Despite of your restriction not to reconfigure your foreign key, I see only one possible solution with two different modellings here.

But first of all: If you get the error, a foreign key to your model `student` is required, why can't you reconfigure that foreign key?

Second: You want to access the parentmodel of `student` and you've got an foreign key to the model `user`. From a modelling point of view I wonder, how that is useful - as you want to operate with a student, not with a user? Additionally, if your `student`is related to `user` you can access all `user`attributes through `student`. So there is really no point in avoiding the reconfiguration of your foreign key.

So the only two possible (and meaningful) modellings I see are:

**(1)** Let the model `student` inherit from `user`, so `student` has all field's and methods which are implemented to `user`. Then reconfigure the foreign key to `student` (which requires `$ python manage.py makemigrations <app>` and `$ python manage.py migrate <app>`)

or

**(2)**
Define a one-to-one relation between `student` and `user`, so a student is uniquely to a `user`. This also requires to reconfigure your foreign key as describbed in **(1)**.

If `student` does **not** differ from `user` there is an **(3)** option: Proxy models. With proxy models you can implement multiple modelAdmin for one model.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more detailed in my explanation. `Student` does hold a FK to `User`, so one student is linked to one user; the tricky part is that all student related model (e.g. `Todo`, `Class`, 'School`, etc.) hold FKs to `User`, not `Student`. This is an unfortunate design of the schema that I'm not currently in the position to do anything about, so an ideal solution would allow me to add these models as inlines to `StudentForm` in the admin tool. Having `Student` inherit from `User` would've been great, however, that ship has sailed for the moment.

Comment: Then you can work with that `ForeignKey` reverse (see [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)). django provides a manager to get querysets of reversed `ForeignKey` relations. With that you can get the `student` through `user`. I can't tell how an admin-inline might be designed - I never got to that myself. But given the reverse of your existing relation, it should be possible.